# iOS Simulator takes extremely long time to boot first time

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode7

I'm trying to run an iOS simulator (Xcode 7.0.1, OS X Yosemite). However, the first time I run the simulator, it takes a very long time to boot up (80-120 seconds), which is causing my automation testing to time out. If I close the simulator and re-launch the same one, it will boot up in about 5-8 seconds. Launching a different device will cause the long boot up time again.

I have tried resetting the content and settings of the simulator, deleting and re-downloading simulators, and uninstalling and reinstalling Xcode.

This machine is a Parallels Desktop VM running on a 2012 Mac Mini. While I do not believe this to be a resource issue (the simulator runs just fine with the second launch), I have tried increasing ram and video memory to the VM with no success.

Comment: 80-120 seconds consider really fast for me. It takes more than 5 minutes to launch simulator for my iMac late 2012. It's even worse than an android emulator now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution so far has been to pre-boot the Simulator prior to needing it for automation. I consider this somewhat hackish, but it does get the job done.

```
xcrun instruments -w "Simulator Name Here"
sleep 120
```

This will launch the simulator, then sleep for a couple minutes before proceeding on to whatever else you need the simulator for.

Answer (score 7):

Had the same issue after updating to Xcode 7 on my iMac (late 2013). And yesterday I've succeeded to resolve it by doing 2 steps (unfortunately, I don't know which did really help):

1. I had Xcode 6 installed side by side with Xcode 7. So I've deleted Xcode 6 instance.
2. Open Xcode 7, go to Window -> Devices and delete all listed iOS simulators you have there. Close & re-start Xcode. Go to Window -> Devices again and add only simulators you need (in my case I've added iPhone 6 iOS 8, iPhone 6s iOS 9, iPad Air 2 iOS 9). You can add more simulators later on as you need them. Also, not sure if this is critical, I've selected no paired watchOS device for simulators I've added.

After completing these steps, my simulator cold start was significantly imporoved - it takes now like 30-40seconds max for a cold start. Before that it was 3-4minutes and first debugger attach attempt always failed.

Hope, this will be helpful for somebody.

Comment: Hi - I tried #2 and it didnt make any difference to me.

Answer (score 1):

At first boot, the sim device will go through initial setup just like a real device.  Taking 2 minutes is quite a long time on modern systems but not that unheard of, especially if you're not on an SSD.  I suggest you watch the sim device's system.log to see what tasks are occurring during the boot process and keep an eye out for any errors that might indicate what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run the iPhone6S simulator on my Macbook Air, and it just hung at the game center login screen. It hung for 10 minutes. I had 50% scale on the simulator window. Then I tried to reduce the scale even more, and immediately it passed the GC login screen.

My guess is that my little Air has don't have time to do anything else but updating the simulator screen at high scales, and when I reduced the scale it had time to bother with the game center login functionality. My simulator widow is the size of a stamp now. :)

Puh. I've had this simulator problem for weeks...

Comment: This is a different issue - you're past the simulator booting.