# Xcode simulator Version 10.2 is booting first time extremely slow

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode10.2

I am having problem with my Xcode simulator. Its booting up extremely slow. It tooks almost half an hour or more than that sometimes. I don't know whats the reason.

This is the system info -
Xcode version - Version 10.2 (10E125)
Xcode simulator - Version 10.2 (SimulatorApp-880.5 CoreSimulator-587.35)
RAM - 8GB

I tried couple of ways.

1)
[iOS Simulator takes extremely long time to boot first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33025054/ios-simulator-takes-extremely-long-time-to-boot-first-time)

2) Also I have erased contents and settings data - 
$ xcrun simctl erase all

3) There is no issue with slower animation. It's unchecked.

None of these worked for me. Please let me know the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was booting slower because of less RAM memory available. Due to excessive software installed on my PC everything freezes mostly chrome browser. I have uninstalled all unnecessary softwares and tools and freed memory on RAM.

This helps me !!